# Powershell script FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, ftpwebrequest

I need to automate a FTP process which downloads the most recent files from the previous day the files all have different names and all end with the *1.DAT extension.

I have in the passed had real success using the FTP Client module and this is what i normally use when uploading and downloading files using FTP. The problem I have hit is that this works with the -Credentials switch and expects the password to be encrypted, the destination  ftp server which is not in my control does not understand the credentails object when it is passed to the server and fails with a 550 error

I have seen many other posts on this site about using FTP with powershell but none really seem to be doing what i want in terms of getting only the previous days files.

can anyone help

Thank you

code as requested

`try

{
    Add-Type -Path WinSCPnet.dll

```
# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
$sessionOptions.HostName = "IPServer"
$sessionOptions.UserName = "username"
$sessionOptions.Password = "Password"
$sessionOptions.PortNumber = 21 
#$sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"



$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.XmlLogPath = "D:\scripts\Xml.log"
#$session.SessionLogPath = "D:\scripts\Logs\Session.log"


$date = Get-Date
$date1 =$date.AddDays(-1)
$date2str = $date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    $localPath = "D:\Eastcoast\Input\Data\Barcode_files"
    $remotePath = "/"

    # Gel list of files in the directory
    $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

    # Select the most recent file
    $latest = $directoryInfo.Files | Where-Object { -not $_.IsDirectory}

        Foreach ($file in $latest) { 
        $filedate = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        If ( $filedate -eq $date2str) { $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $latest.Name), $localPath).Check()}

        }`
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: Hi well since i posted i have found something which looks like it will do the job using WinSCPnet.dll and powershell. the only problem i have is that when i try and execute the  $session.Open($sessionOptions) i get the error Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." are you able to help with this?

Comment: another update i have updated the code and can now get back the correct dates back from the source FTP server but when I try to execute the download it fails does anyone know what i am doing wrong. I have updated the code this is the error i now get

Comment: 'At line:3 char:45 If ($filedate -eq $date2str) { $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFil ...+
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionRemoteException
Exception calling "Check" with "0" argument(s): "Can't get attributes of file '/AVB_A4461b110720141.DAT'